# MySQL Workbench save values

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I already googled and found a question here on stackoverflow, but unfortunately for an older version where obviously has changed the GUI.

My problem: I edit something in a row, delete, edit, add, but I can't find any way to save it and apply that. If I close the table, it asks me to apply the changes, where I press yes and it'll work, but this is not the method I am looking for.

So, how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the latest version of MySQL Workbench installed, and there's an "Apply" button [all the way to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNcQo.png):

[image]

Comment: Now I can see it. Thank you very much, didn't notice that!

Comment: Yeah, I know, I remember looking for it like crazy myself.